# Django FSM - get_available_FIELD_transitions

Tags: django, django-fsm

Using django_fsm I need to get the available transitions a list. When using the following code I do get a `<generator object get_available_FIELD_transitions at 0x10b9ba660>`

```
obj = MyModel.objects.get(pk=object_id)
transitions = obj.get_available_status_transitions()
print(transitions)
```

Instead I would like to get a list of transitions like `['PENDING', 'CLOSED']`

Answer (score 1):

The generator has everything you need, it just needs iterating. To get what you want, you can just convert it to a list:

```py
transitions = list(obj.get_available_status_transitions())
```

You might want to read up on [generators](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions) in Python, they're very useful.

Answer (score 1):

Generators are iterable python objects. See [Generators](https://wiki.python.org/moin/Generators)

This will print each item

```
    transitions = list(obj.get_available_state_transitions())
    print(transitions)
```

I found this from the test cases of django-fsm
[Django-fsm TestCase](https://github.com/viewflow/django-fsm/blob/master/tests/testapp/tests/test_custom_data.py)